# Run multiple SELECTs in DB Browser for SQLite with multiple results

Tags: sqlite

Run multiple SELECTs in DB Browser for SQLite with multiple results - is it possible?

Here I have 2 selects, but in results panel I can see the results from only the last one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to run multiple selects, but you can run multiple writes if you separate the lines with semi-colons:

```
update Item set Description = 'Protection'  where no = 'EXTSOFAUARD';
update Item set Description = 'Fabric'  where no = 'FABRIC1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can.

However, You can have multiple tabs (click the open tab (leftmost) icon) and have separate queries in the tabs. It's then just a matter of switching between tabs.

Navicat has this feature/capability, even then the results are in separate tabs.

e.g. :-

[image]